# Hide dialog title at the startup of an activity

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-lifecycle

I have an pop-up dialog, that need to display at the start up of an activity. To start the popup at start up, I have placed it on **onStart()**. That works fine, but it displaying the blank title on the pop-up dialog. To Removed this, I have tried with `dialog.requestWindowFeature(dialog.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` 
 But this getting and runtime exception. below is the OnStart() method:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_layout);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(dialog.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 

        Button mYes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button mNo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mYes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();

            }
        });
        mMoveToWallet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

**Exception:** `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature must be called before adding to the content.`
Please help me on this.
Thanks' in advance.

Comment: why you need to put dialog inside onstart method? You can put it inside oncreate method of activity.

Comment: To make the dialog visable at the start of the activity. Placing it inside OnCreate/onStart is not issue with me.

Comment: post. your. stacktrace.

Comment: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature must be called before adding to the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this property of dialog**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

**Remove this**

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(dialog.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

**UPDATE**

***try this style***

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Update 2:
Add below style to the style.xml and use it on dialog declaration

```
<style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
```

This is correctly acceptable as it extends android's Theme.Dialog style.

Comment: It is removing the title but it also placing my popup dialog to the top of the layout instead of center.

Comment: Sir, modifying your logic, i shape it to my need, making a custom style.

Comment: Ok NP you can do by inherit the on of above style

Comment: Thank u sir,I have solved the problem. I need to put the answer here or I need to put the solution as an answer. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(dialog.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Keep this line before the setContentView method.